# .htaccess RewriteRule backreference order

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a question about htaccess rewriting rule.

Is it possible to convert this url:

*www.site.com/en/test*

In something like this:

*www.site.com/test.php?language=en*

I tried to use this RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*)$ $1.php?language=$2
```

But in some online testing tool the result URL was:

*www.site.com/en.php?language=test*

Thank you in advance.
Mat

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this confusion is that you've reversed the matches. When you use references, the first reference in the match is always $1, the second is $2 and so on.

Here's what you did, looking only at the parentheses:

```
([a-z][a-z]) = first match, places "en" in $1 
(.*) = second match, places "test" in $2
```

So you simply need to reverse them in your output, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*)$ $2.php?language=$1
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast reply.
I tried also changing the backreference order ($1 with $2) but nothing change.

Comment: I use this tool for the test: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ (if you want to try)

Comment: That tool doesn't handle backreferences properly. You can enter any number and it will still use the backreferences in the order they are created rather than in the order you tell it to. You need to actually try it out in your configuration before you say it doesn't work.

Comment: The answer was correct and needed a pass mark...  Always try your config in the real environment as those online tools are programmed overlay and sometimes buggy or not finished...